# How Can I make gsutil cp skip false symlinks?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am using gsutil to upload a folder which contains symlinks, the problem is that some of these files are false symlinks ( Unfortunately, that's the case)

Here is an example of the command I am using:

```
gsutil -m cp -c -n -e -L output-upload.log -r output gs://my-storage
```

and I get the following:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output/1231/file.mp4'
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
```

Is there a way to make gsutil skip this file or fail safely without stopping the upload ?

Comment: I believe this is a bug in gsutil cp -e since that option should exclude symlinks, so let's follow up on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/403 (thanks for filing that GitHub issue!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in gsutil (which it looks like you reported [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/403)) and it will be fixed in gsutil 4.23.